# charm proof issues a "relation server has no hooks" warning

Tags: juju, charms

When I run `charm proof <path_to_charm_folder>` I get the following warning.

> W: relation server has no hooks

What does this mean and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: What does your `metadata.yaml` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a warning about a nonexistent relation defined in your `metadata.yaml` file.

Does not mean there is something wrong with your Charm and can be ignored. Your Charm will probably work normally so no need to worry.

Comment: BTW I opened https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-tools/+bug/893363 because this is actually an erroneous warning that should be removed.